# How to configure SSL on Spring Boot - Angular app on EC2 instance

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-ec2

I can't get my backend to send data after switching to secure connection.

I was able to successfully configure SSL with ssl_mod on Apache web server that serves my Angular app on AWS Linux 2 instance, the site is secure - but my Spring Boot backend is not responding, it is not sending any data. When I additionally convert .crt and .key files to PK12 that Spring understands and I use it in Spring app - I get this error:

```
net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

I've tried using AWS Load Balancer, but same thing happens, frontend is loaded in secure environment, but backend is not sending any data even after I change backend calls from http to https://my-site.com. I've tried following documentation and added this to my backend app properties file:

```
server.tomcat.remoteip.remote-ip-header=x-forwarded-for
server.tomcat.remoteip.protocol-header=x-forwarded-proto
```

and security configuration upgraded with this:

```
 http.requiresChannel().anyRequest().requiresSecure()...
```

- but to no avail.

Lastly, I created a new instance on EC2 and this time I didn't configure apache for the frontend on linux, I just used SSL certificate on my backend app with following properties:

```
server.ssl.enabled=true
server.ssl.key-store=/etc/ssl/mydomain_com.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password=******
server.ssl.key-alias=mydomain
```

To no avail, now my site doesn't load at all. I'm despearate, struggling with this for a week now. What is the procedure for a full stack app? How do I do it?

Comment: Have you checked the security group for your backend? Does allow HTTPS connections on port 443? Also, what errors do you get in your browser's console when the Angular app tries to connect to the backed?

Comment: Security group on AWS allows HTTPS on port 433. After configuring application.properties file for SSL stuff - I get this error:

net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Comment: On my Firefox console I get this error: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://zoran-dzoic.com:8080/product-category. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).

But I know that I have handled CORS in my backend app properly. So this is strange.

Answer (score 0):

Let me respond because on the same day I asked the question - I found a solution. The solution was - converting free SSL certificate with the help of this website:

https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-converter.html

After I've plugged it in my Spring Boot app - it works. Before that, I made the conversion with OpenSSL on Windows, and it seems it was faulty. I'm so happy now... I read so many articles on this website on my one and a half year journey of learning to code - and got stuck on the last step. I'm so happy. Thank you all for this amazing website and all the help. I love you! I'm proud of being a part of this programming community... the best humor, the best people!

Peace